# Unable to create OpenVPN Stunnel tunnel

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, internet, init.d

I want a setup like this:

OpenVPN Client <==> Stunnel Client <==> INTERNET <==> Stunnel Server <==> OpenVPN Server

(OpenVPN client only talks to Stunnel client and so on and so forth)

Basically I want to tunnel my OpenVPN connection over Stunnel. I have two ubuntu machines and two GL-INET VPN Routers.

Problem:
After setting configurations of stunnel and OpenVPN client and server up though, looks like packets from OpenVPN client aren't able to reach stunnel server. I get the Connection Refused (111) Error on Stunnel client (running on ubuntu machine).

Following are details of various endpoints:

OpenVPN client: GL-Inet OpenVPN router, LAN Connected to Bell Main Router

Stunnel Client: Ubuntu, LAN Connected to Bell Main Router

Stunnel Server: Ubuntu, LAN Connected to a Main wifi Router

OpenVPN Server: Ubuntu, LAN Connected to a Main wifi Router

Now, when I initiate connection on the OpenVPN Client, I get the following error on UBUNTU Client:
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG3[366]: s_connect: connect 142.198.10.52:443: Connection refused (111)

How can I fix this and connect to Stunnel server and eventually OpenVPN?

=======================================

Configurations:

OpenVPN Client:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 192.168.8.229 2222
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth SHA256 
cipher AES-256-GCM
nice 0
mute 5
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDCzCCAfOgAwIBAgIUQrgdPuYAe1NsB5pLVpHmJv35mUswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICtTCCAZ0CFG2ihbYNKpQ9vcnoU8/F+yuYalEPMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMBUx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDhutA0gHv08iEn
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Client STUNNEL config:

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4

# https://www.stunnel.org/faq.html
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1

debug = 7

#[yahoo_imaps-client]
#client = yes
#accept = 127.0.0.1:143
#connect = imap.mail.yahoo.com:993
# This requires ca-certificates package
#CApath = /etc/ssl/certs/
#verifyChain = yes
#checkHost = imap.mail.yahoo.com

[ssh_tls-server]
client = yes
accept = 2222
connect = 142.198.10.52:443
PSKsecrets = /etc/stunnel/psk1.txt
```

Client connection logs:

```
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[main]: FD=4 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[main]: FD=9 events=0x2001 revents=0x1
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[main]: Service [ssh_tls-server] accepted (FD=3) from 192.168.8.1:37032
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: Service [ssh_tls-server] started
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: Setting local socket options (FD=3)
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG5[366]: Service [ssh_tls-server] accepted connection from 192.168.8.1:37032
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG6[366]: s_connect: connecting 142.198.10.52:443
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 142.198.10.52:443: waiting 10 seconds
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: FD=6 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: FD=11 events=0x2005 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG3[366]: s_connect: connect 142.198.10.52:443: Connection refused (111)
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG3[366]: No more addresses to connect
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG5[366]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: Local descriptor (FD=3) closed
2023.11.04 21:42:19 LOG7[366]: Service [ssh_tls-server] finished (0 left)
```

Server OpenVPN:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 142.198.10.52 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth SHA256 
cipher AES-256-GCM
nice 0
mute 5
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDCzCCAfOgAwIBAgIUQrgdPuYAe1NsB5pLVpHmJv35mUswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICtTCCAZ0CFG2ihbYNKpQ9vcnoU8/F+yuYalEPMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMBUx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDhutA0gHv08iEn
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Server Ubuntu Stunnel:

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4

# https://www.stunnel.org/faq.html
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1

debug = 7 

#[yahoo_imaps-client]
#client = yes
#accept = 127.0.0.1:143
#connect = imap.mail.yahoo.com:993
# This requires ca-certificates package
#CApath = /etc/ssl/certs/
#verifyChain = yes
#checkHost = imap.mail.yahoo.com

[openvpn]
client = no 
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
accept = 192.168.2.167:9999 
connect = 192.168.2.75:1194 
ciphers = PSK
PSKsecrets = /etc/stunnel/psk1.txt
```

Server Init Logs (nothing happens when connection is initiated though):

Server Init Logs

```
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[main]: Found 1 ready file descriptor(s)
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[main]: FD=4 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[main]: FD=9 events=0x2001 revents=0x1
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[main]: Service [openvpn] accepted (FD=3) from 172.104.242.173:40259
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[0]: Service [openvpn] started
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[0]: Setting local socket options (FD=3)
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG5[0]: Service [openvpn] accepted connection from 172.104.242.173:40259
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG6[0]: Peer certificate not required
2023.11.04 17:31:57 LOG7[0]: TLS state (accept): before SSL initialization
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG6[0]: ssl_start: s_poll_wait: TIMEOUTbusy exceeded: sending reset
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG7[0]: FD=6 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG7[0]: FD=3 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG5[0]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG7[0]: Local descriptor (FD=3) closed
2023.11.04 17:36:57 LOG7[0]: Service [openvpn] finished (0 left)
```